# How to use foreach in javascript with my array?

Tags: javascript

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "IT-DSM-WI-003-RU_Управление BI Cloud_Ред.03.pdf",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/BI Cloud/IT-DSM-WI-003-RU_Управление BI Cloud_Ред.03.pdf?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "Cloud",
      "section": "Cloud"
    },
    {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "IT-DSM-WI-002-RU_Разграничение прав доступа к BI Cloud_Ред.02.pdf",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/BI Cloud/IT-DSM-WI-002-RU_Разграничение прав доступа к BI Cloud_Ред.02.pdf?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "Cloud",
      "section": "Cloud"
    },
    {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "Инструкция_Галерея.docx",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/Life/Инструкция_Галерея.docx?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "ERP: Первые шаги",
      "section": "1C: ERP"
    };

for (i = 0; i < myObj.cars.length; i++) {
  x += myObj.name[i]  +=  myObj.url[i]  += myObj.type[i] + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
</script>
```

I have that array by use get method and i need to write by 'for' in different category by type ? How to use for function correct? where is my mistake?

Comment: `i < myObj.cars.length;` but there is no `cars` property

Comment: Your JavaScript is invalid. The value assigned to `myObj` is not a valid array declaration.

Comment: what is this : `x += myObj.name[i]  +=  myObj.url[i]  += myObj.type[i] + "<br>";` supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myObj` contains no property named `cars`.
You could make `myObj` an array and iterate over it :

```js
var myObj, i, x = "";
myObj = [{
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "IT-DSM-WI-003-RU_Управление BI Cloud_Ред.03.pdf",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/BI Cloud/IT-DSM-WI-003-RU_Управление BI Cloud_Ред.03.pdf?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "Cloud",
      "section": "Cloud"
    },
    {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "IT-DSM-WI-002-RU_Разграничение прав доступа к BI Cloud_Ред.02.pdf",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/BI Cloud/IT-DSM-WI-002-RU_Разграничение прав доступа к BI Cloud_Ред.02.pdf?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "Cloud",
      "section": "Cloud"
    },
    {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "Инструкция_Галерея.docx",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/Life/Инструкция_Галерея.docx?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "ERP: Первые шаги",
      "section": "1C: ERP"
    }];

for (i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
  x += myObj[i].name  +=  myObj[i].url  += myObj[i].type + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object is invalid this is ending after your first brackets, when you'll have changed it 
this should loop through

```
for(let obj in myObj){

}
```

and to get your vals thats more like 
myObj[obj].type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `map` property of `Array` to achieve this more easily. Check the code below.
Also I would suggest using some kind of block level html element to render this data since you are kind of creating a list. So I use a `li` and `br` for extra line space instead of only `br`. Although the extra space is better provided using CSS.

```js
const myObj = [{
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "IT-DSM-WI-003-RU_Управление BI Cloud_Ред.03.pdf",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/BI Cloud/IT-DSM-WI-003-RU_Управление BI Cloud_Ред.03.pdf?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "Cloud",
      "section": "Cloud"
    },
    {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "IT-DSM-WI-002-RU_Разграничение прав доступа к BI Cloud_Ред.02.pdf",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/BI Cloud/IT-DSM-WI-002-RU_Разграничение прав доступа к BI Cloud_Ред.02.pdf?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "Cloud",
      "section": "Cloud"
    },
    {
      "__type": "DocumentLibraryHelps.Methods.Instruction",
      "name": "Инструкция_Галерея.docx",
      "url": "https://cloud.bi-group.org/instr/Life/Инструкция_Галерея.docx?web=1",
      "type": "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile",
      "category": "ERP: Первые шаги",
      "section": "1C: ERP"
    }];
    
const txt = myObj.map(obj=>'<li>'+obj.name+obj.type+obj.url+'</li><br>').join('');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```